# System resume kills wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, wifi, wpa

Using debian distros for a few years.  All distros from the last few years seem to share a wierd wpa_supplicant issue.  Has anyone else attempted to solve/understand this issue during sleep/resume?

When system goes to sleep, upon resuming wpa_supplicant stops working.  Tried the following to get wpa_supplicant to allow connection to networks....

```
# service wicd stop
```

```
# wpa_action wlan0 reload
```

```
sudo dhcpcd --release wlan0
```

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid off
```

```
#sudo iwconfig wlan0 ap off
```

```
#service network-manager stop
```

```
#service networking stop
```

```
# ifconfig wlan0 down
```

```
#ip link set wlan0 down
```

```
#rfkill unblock all
```

```
service network-manager status | grep 'active'
```

no network connections active

Then restart EVERYTHING -> still wpa_supplicant reports "error bad password" via nmcli and/or wicd

restart computer -> everything works again !  

What causes this wpa_supplicant error? What else interacts with wpa_supplicant establishing connections - that was not listed above?

Comment: Never seen any of that, but all workstations are running Fedora, CentOS or RHEL. So... Add `-dd` to its command line options to get lots of extra debugging output, reproduce the fault, and check what gets logged.